# Print lines of wbinfo -u matching pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a Redhat 6.8 cluster with several nodes in it that I'm trying to sync the Active Directory UID and GID to utilizing winbind. I am attempting to sync the output of wbinfo -u to all the nodes but only want the relevant AD accounts with the uid and gid fields populated. I tried this with:

```
for i in `wbinfo -u`; do id ${i} | awk '/uid/{ print $0}' ; done
```

I end up getting all of the wbinfo -u results as if I ran it by itself.

Is there a way to just grep/awk/sed the results with uid in the beginning of it? I apologize for not showing the output of what I ran, this system isn't connected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I figured it out. When I run the:

for i in `wbinfo -u`; do id ${i} ; done

It outputs all of the errors on accounts without uid/gid as well as the accounts with the successful attempts with uid/gid to the screen, but when I redirected the output of the command to /tmp/test:

for i in `wbinfo -u`; do id ${i} ; done > /tmp/test

It only outputs the successful results, which is what I needed. So I guess 'id' when redirected only shows successful attempts. Go figure. Thanks guys.